# Adding Strings to txt file

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

So here's the code

```
public class HospitalManager {
  Writer write = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Tigra\\Desktop\\TikDevExp\\Patient.txt");
  FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Patient.txt");
  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

  public HospitalManager() throws IOException {
  }

  public Patient registerPatient(Patient p1) {
    out.println("=Adding new patient=");
    out.println("Please enter the name");
    Scanner setter = new Scanner(System.in);
    p1.name = setter.nextLine();
    out.println("Enter the surname");
    p1.surName = setter.nextLine();
    out.println("Enter the diagnosys");
    p1.diagnose = setter.nextLine();

    return p1;
}

public void addPatient(Patient addThisOne, List<String> patientList) {
  try {
    bw.append(addThisOne.name + ", " + addThisOne.surName + ", " + addThisOne.diagnose);
    bw.newLine();
    bw.close();
  } catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

}
```

its in HospitalManager class. In main code I have an instance for that class, and I use `addPatient()` on it. The thing is, I need it to add String in Patient.txt file each time I use that method. I need String to be added to new line in file, but instead, it stores only first use of `addPatient()`, second and further uses of method being simply ignored, can you please tell me what can I do to add new line with String each time `addPatient()` is used?

Comment: What do you mean by "further uses of method being simply ignored"? Do you get any exception? I think the problem is that you are closing BufferedWriter bw.close();

Comment: like if I add "Hello World" into txt file through that method, it adds "Hello World" to file, but if I use the method second time and input something else, its not adding the String into file, file contains only first string I gave to him which is "Hello World". Exception is not happening in this case, it seems its just ignoring every use of the Method except first use.

I was thinking about bw.close(). tried to remove it from code and run program, but in that case its not saving even first inputed String...

Comment: Of course it does not work without bw.close() because you do not flush your buffer. Try calling bw.close() after all invocations of addPatient

Comment: should I also add bw.flush() after bw.append() ??

Comment: bw.close flushes the buffer, but also closes the writer. If you want to write something and it should occur immediately in the file, then flush() might be a good idea - but remember to call bw.close() after all operations.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

After you `close` a `Writer`, you can't write to it anymore. So, if you want to write to the same file again, you will have to open it each time

```
public class HospitalManager {
  // The Writer write isn't used in your code
  // fw and bw will be declared in addPatient

  public HospitalManager() { // No IOExceptions here anymore
  }

  public Patient registerPatient(Patient p1) {
    out.println("=Adding new patient=");
    out.println("Please enter the name");
    Scanner setter = new Scanner(System.in);
    p1.name = setter.nextLine();
    out.println("Enter the surname");
    p1.surName = setter.nextLine();
    out.println("Enter the diagnosys");
    p1.diagnose = setter.nextLine();

    return p1;
}

public void addPatient(Patient addThisOne, List<String> patientList) {
  // Declare variables outside of the block so they can be
  // referenced in finally
  FileWriter fw;
  BufferedWriter bw;
  try {
    fw = new FileWriter("Patient.txt");
    bw = new BufferedWriter(bw);
    bw.append(addThisOne.name + ", " + addThisOne.surName + ", " + addThisOne.diagnose);
    bw.newLine();
    bw.close();
  } catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Alternatively, you could keep the file open until the main code knows that it won't add any other patients.

```
public class HospitalManager {
  FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Patient.txt");
  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

  public HospitalManager() throws IOException {
  }

  public Patient registerPatient(Patient p1) {
    out.println("=Adding new patient=");
    out.println("Please enter the name");
    Scanner setter = new Scanner(System.in);
    p1.name = setter.nextLine();
    out.println("Enter the surname");
    p1.surName = setter.nextLine();
    out.println("Enter the diagnosys");
    p1.diagnose = setter.nextLine();

    return p1;
}

public void addPatient(Patient addThisOne, List<String> patientList) {
  try {
    bw.append(addThisOne.name + ", " + addThisOne.surName + ", " + addThisOne.diagnose);
    bw.newLine();
    // Don't close the file, but write the contents of the buffer
    bw.flush();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

// Call this when no more patients are going to be added
public void done() {
  try {
    bw.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
}
```